# How to select the SQL database values that has the same name and sum up their corresponded values

Tags: c#, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZbuZ.png)

I want to add all the liters of the cattle that is named Camel without getting interrupted by other Cattle catagories ,... Anyone can help.. this is for a **c# project** though

```
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
"insert into NewMilk(ProviderName,Cattle,Liter,[Price/liter],Salary,Date) values('" +
    txtNewMilkName.Text + "', '" + txtNewMilkCattle.Text + "', '" + 
    txtNewMilkLiter.Text + "', '" + txtNewMilkPrice.Text + "', '" +
    txtNewMilkSalary.Text + "', '" + label11.Text + "')", con);
sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Data is Saved Succesfully...!");
txtNewMilkName.Clear();
txtNewMilkCattle.Clear();
txtNewMilkLiter.Clear();
txtNewMilkPrice.Clear();
txtNewMilkSalary.Clear();
```

i added to the database using this code but i want to retrieve all the Value of the Liters that has found in One of the cattle Names ...

forexample if i want the the total sum of the the cattle that has been saved under the cattle name cow then i can only add the values of the row liters under cow ,...

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: If I understand the question correct, this is a fairly simple SQL query. Can you show what you've done so far and what's not working?

Comment: You should do two things - first post the source data directly in your question so we dont have to go and look at the image, and second post what you expect as the result set. Dummy it up in excel if you need to. You will get a quick and simple answer if you do that. Oh, and also if you have already tried a sql statement post that in the question as well.

Comment: i edited  it .... there is a column name Cattle that has differnet catagory of cattles under it (COW, buffolo, camel, goat)  ..All cattles has a column named "Liter" ... then i want to add up all the Liters under Cow, Buffolo, camel, and goat separately

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This prose is extremely unclear.--Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. See the edit help re block & inline formats for code & for quotes. [ask] [Help] PS When debugging, isolate your problem to one software layer at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by Cattle

```
SELECT Cattle, SUM(Liter) AS TotalLiter
FROM NewMilk
GROUP BY Cattle
ORDER BY Cattle
```

See: [SQL GROUP BY Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Or if you need the total of only one specific cattle type

```
SELECT SUM(Liter) AS TotalLiter
FROM NewMilk
WHERE Cattle = 'Cow'
```

You can execute a SQL command returning rows like this

```
string sql = "SELECT Cattle, SUM(Liter) AS TotalLiter ... "; // 1st SQL example.
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
    con.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()) {
        string cattle = reader.GetString(0); // 1st column
        int total = reader.GetInt32(1); // 2nd column
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, if you have only one row with one column, i.e. one result value

```
string sql = "SELECT SUM(Liter) AS TotalLiter ... ";  // 2nd SQL example.
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
    con.Open();
    int total = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    ...
}
```

---

See also: [The Right Way to Query a Database: Parameterizing your SQL Queries.](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-the-right-way-to-query-a-database-parameterizing-your-sql-queries/)

Comment: how can i use this in  C# code then '

Comment: the values under the column of the cattle has been assigned to the string cattle and so as the Liter... how can it add up the string cattle of the liter that only says Cow

Comment: you have been so helpful thanks !!!